# Ivory google map facade

Tags: php, google-maps

I want to simplify this process of creating map, putting markers on it according to `Place` objects from my database, creating info windows. Using [egeloen/ivory-google-map](https://github.com/egeloen/ivory-google-map) library, I've written a facade for this proccess.

```
class PlaceMap
{
    protected $map;

    protected $templating;

    protected $places = [];

    public function __construct(Map $map, \Twig_Environment $templating)
    {
        $this->map = $map;
        $this->templating = $templating;

        $this->map->setStylesheetOption('width', '100%');
        $this->map->setStylesheetOption('height', '90vh');
        $this->map->setCenter(new Coordinate(55.117100, 23.940332));
        $this->map->setMapOption('zoom', 7);
    }

    public function setPlaces(array $places)
    {
        $this->places = $places;
    }

    public function getMap()
    {
        $this->process();

        return $this->map;
    }

    protected function process()
    {
        $markers = [];
        $events = [];

        foreach ($this->places as $place) {
            $marker = $this->placeToMarker($place);
            $window = $this->getPlaceInfoWindow($place);

            $marker->setInfoWindow($window);

            $events = array_merge($events, $this->createMarkerClickEvents($marker, $window));
            $markers[] = $marker;
        }

        $this->getMarkerCluster()->setMarkers($markers);
        $this->map->getEventManager()->setDomEvents($events);

    }

    protected function placeToMarker(Place $place)
    {
        return new Marker(
            new Coordinate($place->getLatitude(), $place->getLongitude())
        );
    }

    protected function getPlaceInfoWindow(Place $place)
    {
        return new InfoWindow($this->getInfoWindowContent($place));
    }

    protected function getMarkerCluster()
    {
        $cluster = $this->map->getOverlayManager()->getMarkerCluster();
        $cluster->setType(MarkerClusterType::MARKER_CLUSTERER);
        $cluster->setOption('imagePath', 'https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/raw/gh-pages/images/m');

        return $cluster;
    }

    protected function getInfoWindowContent(Place $place)
    {
        return $this->templating->render('AppBundle::place_infowindow.html.twig', ['place' => $place]);
    }

    protected function createMarkerClickEvents(Marker $marker, InfoWindow $window)
    {
        return [new Event($marker->getVariable(), MouseEvent::CLICK, $this->getMarkerClickHandler($window))];
    }

    protected function getMarkerClickHandler(InfoWindow $window)
    {
        return "function () {
            if (currentInfoWindow) {
                currentInfoWindow.close();
            }
                    
            {$window->getVariable()}.open({$this->map->getVariable()}, this);
                    
            currentInfoWindow = {$window->getVariable()};
        }";
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
$placeMap = new PlaceMap(new Map(), $this->get('templating'));
$placeMap->setPlaces($places);

$mapInstance = $placeMap->getMap();
```

Is this a proper usecase to use a facade patter? Should I pass the instance of `Map` to the facade constructor? What about all the Marker, InfoWindow, Event objects, that I use inside a facade? Is it ok to instantiate them in the facade?

**EDIT:**
According to Mike advices, I made a MapFactory, that is responsible for creating static/editable map from passed options.

```
class MapFactory
{
    const CLUSTER_IMAGE_URI = 'https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/raw/gh-pages/images/m';

    public static function buildMap(Coordinate $mapCenter, array $places = [], array $mapOptions = [], $isEditableMap = false)
    {
        $map = new Map();

        $defaultOptions = [
            'zoom' => 7
        ];

        $mapOptions = array_merge($mapOptions, $defaultOptions);

        $map->setCenter($mapCenter);
        $map->setMapOptions($mapOptions);

        $markers = [];

        foreach ($places as $place) {
            $marker = new Marker(new Coordinate($place->getLatitude(), $place->getLongitude()));
            $marker->setOption('draggable', $isEditableMap);

            if ($isEditableMap) {
                // initiate events for editable markers, infowindow content for editable marker
            } else {
                // initiate events for static markers, infowindow content for static marker
            }

            $markers[] = $marker;
        }

        if ($isEditableMap) {
            $map->getOverlayManager()->setMarkers($markers);
        } else {
            $cluster = $map->getOverlayManager()->getMarkerCluster();
            $cluster->setType(MarkerClusterType::MARKER_CLUSTERER);
            $cluster->setOption('imagePath', self::CLUSTER_IMAGE_URI);

            $cluster->setMarkers($markers);
        }

        return $map;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
$center = new Coordinate(55.117100, 23.940332);
$places = $repository->findAll();

$map = MapFactory::buildMap($center, $places);
```

It looks like there is too much code in a factory method. Should I split some related part to other protected static methods? Or is it too much lifting for a factory to create map, initiate markers on it, sent infoWindows and event handlers?

While reading a articles on factory pattern I noticed, that they are used to instantiante multiple different type of objects and not to encapsulate logic.

Answer (score 1):

Since Places is such a hard dependency in this process, I would consider passing that as a dependency rather than breaking this up across multiple steps.  I would even question the need for whether `PlaceMap` needs to be a concrete class vs. a simple statically accessed factory.

Usage in this case might be like:

```
$mapInstance = PlaceMap::buildMap(
    new Map(),
    array $places,
    $this->get('templating')
);
```

This approach would allow you to remove `setPlaces()` and `getMaps()` methods such that you only maintain a single public interface for a single creation step.

---

> ```
> public function __construct(Map $map, \Twig_Environment $templating)
> {
>     $this->map = $map;
>     $this->templating = $templating;
>
>     $this->map->setStylesheetOption('width', '100%');
>     $this->map->setStylesheetOption('height', '90vh');
>     $this->map->setCenter(new Coordinate(55.117100, 23.940332));
>     $this->map->setMapOption('zoom', 7);
> }
> ```

In your constructor, you are doing a lot of manipulations on the passed `Map` object. I would think that since you are passing this in as a dependency, it should already have it's default values set, eliminating need for this code here. You might also consider being able to pass in a config object, `Coordinate` object or similar to set as default location on map.

I don't like defaults hard-coded in this way.  Perhaps defaults should be constants on class, or you simply require that config data be passed in.

---

> ```
> protected function createMarkerClickEvents(Marker $marker, InfoWindow $window)
> {
>     return [new Event($marker->getVariable(), MouseEvent::CLICK, $this->getMarkerClickHandler($window))];
> }
> ```

I question the method name and return signature here.  You are only ever returning a single `Event` (though wrapped in array).  Why not drop `s` from end of method name and remove the array wrapper on return to be less obscure about what is really happening here?  This would also mean related change in `process()` method where you would replace `array_merge()` with more straightforward array push operation.

---

> ```
>     return "function () {
>         if (currentInfoWindow) {
>             currentInfoWindow.close();
>         }
>
>         {$window->getVariable()}.open({$this->map->getVariable()}, this);
>
>         currentInfoWindow = {$window->getVariable()};
>     }";
> ```

Should this string template be either moved out of your class altogether into your display code, or perhaps at a minimum stored as default value on class?

---

> ```
> protected function getInfoWindowContent(Place $place)
>     {
>         return $this->templating->render('AppBundle::place_infowindow.html.twig',
> ```
>
> ['place' => $place]);
>           }

Perhaps `renderInfoWindowContent()`?  `get` typically implies return of some value.

---

Would like to see some minimal comments in certain points, though code is pretty self-explanatory. Consider Doc blocks.

Comment: You suggest using factory pattern in this case?  I have two classes PlaceMap and EditablePlaceMap.  They differ in info window content,  marker click event handler and some marker options.  Is this usecase for factory?

Comment: @nn4n4s Probably.  If that factory is geared towards accepting appropriate dependencies and generating instances of `PlaceMap` or its inheriting classes, I think this makes sense,

Comment: I added a different approach